# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden) ,How i can resolve this error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

app.js :

```
import './bootstrap';

Echo.private('App.Models.Company.' + companyId)
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification);
     });
```

channel.php :

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.Company.{id}', function ($company, $id) {
    return (int) $company->id === (int) $id;
});
```

blade page :

```
<script>
   let companyId = '{{ Auth::id() }}';        
</script>
@vite(['resources/js/app.js'])
```

Comment: Did you uncomment the `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class` in the `config/app.php` ? It located at the bottom part of the file.

Comment: Did it work if you hard coded the id ?

Comment: The code on the app file does not read its channel, even if you stop the channel, the same error remains

Comment: Did you try this? 1. check BroadCastServiceProvider 2. check middleware3. check CORS configuration. Thankyou!

Comment: I had several problems trying to use Laravel Echo, I recommend you to use [this](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction) package, it's much simpler and works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved, because I am using guards in my system, it does not recognize any guards other than the default guard
I defined the guard in the channel route such as :

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.Company.{id}', function ($company, $id) {
         return (int) $company->id === (int) $id;
 },['guards'=>['company']]);
```